# Open Sans appearing as Italic on all live sites but not on local

Tags: css, fonts, local

I have some very strange behaviour happening. On every site I visit that uses Open Sans 400 normal it renders as an italic font in FireFox Developer, all other browsers display Open Sans fine. Strangely though on a local site I'm developing it displays as it should, the live version does not. The font reference/import is the same.

I have tried looking for Open Sans on my computer and couldn't find it so I installed a version locally, this did not fix the issue. I have also mimicked browser font settings in standard FireFox which is displaying the font correctly but this also hasn't made a difference.

Any suggestions would be a big help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Had to restart browser after changing font settings to default.